# How to share images between ACRs in separate tenants using Azure DevOps agents

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

I want to share the same image between two Azure Container Registries. Registries are in different tenants. I build images on self hosted agent with Managed Identity. I have two pools with separate maned identity, because they are also on different tenants.

So on Dev env I have:

- dev pool with dev managed identity
- dev ACR
- dev subscription
- dev tenant

On Prod env I have:

- prod pool with prod managed identity
- prod ACR
- prod subscription
- prod tenant

I don't want to build images twice, but I want to reuse the same image which is alreadu pushed.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can:

- create short-lived token to access dev Container Registry
- pass this token to Prod job to use it in another tenant
- copies images from Dev Container Registry to Prod Container Registry using token

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: ImportImage
    jobs:
      - job: ObtainToken
        displayName: 'Obtain Token'
        pool:
          name: Dev
        steps:
          - script: |
              az login --identity
              az account set --subscription 'Dev'
              token=$(az account get-access-token --query accessToken -o tsv)
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=accessToken;isoutput=true;issecret=true]$token"
            displayName: 'Obtain Access Token'
            name: ObtainToken

      - job: ImportImage
        displayName: 'Import Container Image'
        dependsOn: ObtainToken
        pool:
          name: Prod
        variables:
          accessToken: $[ dependencies.ObtainToken.outputs['ObtainToken.accessToken'] ]
        steps:
          - script: |
              az login --identity
              az account set --subscription 'Prod'
              ##vso[task.setsecret]$(accessToken)
              # Use the obtained token to import the container image from the registry
              az acr import \
                --name prodacr \
                --source devacr.azurecr.io/some_api:20240112.1 \
                --image some_api:20240112.1 \
                --password $(accessToken)
            displayName: 'Import Container Image'
```